# Get the app last running time in android

Tags: android, adb, stat

I am trying to get the app **last running time** (not only my app) in android.
From my understanding, all app is installed in /data/app/.
So, I try to run `stat` command in `adb shell` to obtain the last access time of all apk.

But it is surprising to me that the last access time seems to be the last installed/updated time instead of the running time. Why is it so? I think android system need to "access" the apk in order to load it and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of performance, access time is not updated anymore

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#Criticism_of_atime